# Key error 5 issue when using Jupyter notebook commands into pycharm

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

I stumbled over a issue in which I do not understand or can not find a solution in solving.

The codes I type functions perfectly in my Jupyter Notebook but caused an error when I used PyCharm.

I typed in these codes in PyCharm:

```
df_ticker.loc[df_ticker['Red'] == True, 'Value'] = df_ticker['Open'] - df_ticker['Close']

df_ticker.loc[df_ticker['Red'] == False, 'Value'] = df_ticker['Close'] - df_ticker['Open']
```

Using these codes alone and printing their values are a success.
H

However when matched with these lines of code:

```
for i in range(1, len(df_ticker)):
if df_ticker.Close[i] > df_ticker.Close[i-1] and df_ticker.Red[i] == False and \
        df_ticker.Value.round(decimals = 0)[i] >= df_ticker.Value.round(decimals = 0)[i-1] \
        and not df_ticker.Close[i-1] >= df_ticker [i-2]:
    rise.append(df_ticker.Close[i])
```

it returns this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/benjaminwong/PycharmProjects/Yahoo Finance project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2889, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 97, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1675, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1683, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 5

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/benjaminwong/PycharmProjects/Yahoo Finance project/Rise_Finder 2.py", line 29, in <module>
    and not df_ticker.Close[i-1] >= df_ticker [i-2]:
  File "/Users/benjaminwong/PycharmProjects/Yahoo Finance project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2899, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "/Users/benjaminwong/PycharmProjects/Yahoo Finance project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2891, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 5
```

Please help, Thank you for your time :)

Comment: can you add a standard input and the required output here.

Comment: it was supposed to be df_ticker.Close[i-2] not df_ticker [i-2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
and not df_ticker.Close[i-1] >= df_ticker [i-2]:
```

and

```
KeyError: 5
```

df_ticker.Close[**5**] or df_ticker [**5**] doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

it was supposed to be:

```
df_ticker.Close[i] > df_ticker.Close[i-2]
```

I missed the second Close.